# Can the word 物 refer to a person?

Tags: words

In the [使い分け] part of this [page](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/2034/meaning/m0u/%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E5%88%86%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B/) :

[image]

Comment: It doesnt' answer your question, but maybe you confusion comes from 者{もの}, that can refer to a person.

Comment: Don't worry @Gumamori it's solved, I didn't read correctly the sentences and I thought that [大勢の人を使いこなす] was an example of the first sentence  but it is not the case. Though the first sentence is a little bit misleading according to me because it is supposed to give the complete meaning of the verb 使いこなす but gives only 物 as a possible object of the verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. 物 can't mean a human. It explains 使いこなす and 大勢の人を使いこなす individually.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for this question, I realized it's very silly and I can't delete it now.

Comment: Better to ask the way than to go astray.(聞くは一時の恥、聞かぬは一生の恥)

Comment: でも、「物を使いこなす」と「人を使いこなす」を別々に説明してはいませんよね.・・・　最初に「使いこなす」は「*物*を・・・使う意」としておきながら、次の文で「大勢の人を使いこなす」というように物ではなく人を目的語にしていますから、「物」が人を指すものとして使えないのであれば、最初の説明と矛盾しているように思われるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 厳密にいえば、「使いこなす」と 「大勢の人を使いこなす」ですね。